# How to convert a unicode string written in font A to font B?

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, fonts

Assuming all the required fonts are available on client's machine.

1. Probably, you all could see following
   'stackoverflow' word written in Indic
   Language script : 'स्टैकओवरफ्लो' . A
   quick lookup using Web Developers
   Tools tells that this word is written
   using 'Arial, Liberation Sans..' font
   family. Does that mean Arial font
   supports Indic language scripts? Is it really Arial font?
2. I want to display all such strings in
   another unicode font installed on
   machine. How could I convert it using
   javascript? My understanding is,
   since there is no direct 1-1 mapping
   between these unicode fonts, some
   kind of conversion might be required.
3. How can I map a unicode font to
   normal 101 keys US keyboard? So that
   typing 'stackoverflow' would get
   converted into 'स्टैकओवरफ्लो' if
   proper font is selected. It seems
   using some [tools](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/utilities_fonts.html), this is
   possible. Is this the normal
   approach? Are there any alternatives?

**EDIT1** [This](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040716-00/?p=38413) and [this](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/utilities_fonts.html) resource seem to be helpful.

**EDIT2** Suppose a particular unicode string could be written in Font A as a combination of ALT+0234, ALT+0244, ALT+0221 on numpad. In Font B, same string would be written via different combination like ALT+0212, ALT+0223, ALT+0242. So how could I do this conversion?

**EDIT3** Please see this [image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/734371e5bb.png) for more clarification. See last 2 strings in brackets. Those are the strings I want to convert to and from. Those 2 strings render same Indic string in 2 different fonts.

Comment: I think you need to distinguish between fonts (appearances of sets of glyphs - Arial and Times Roman and Courier are fonts) versus code sets (8859-1 vs Unicode vs ...).  You seem to be asking for code set conversion - not font conversion.

Comment: Uh. Do you mean a *translation* software? Because whatever this indic text means, it’s not a 1:1 character transliteration of “stackoverflow”: the character count doesn’t match. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @jonathan: could you please explain a bit. I've tried to explain my question better in 2nd edit above.

Comment: What you describe is either translation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation) or transliteration (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration). Both are usually a lot more involved than just a simple lookup table.

Comment: @Joachim: its neither translation not transliteration. Please see EDIT3 above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Most modern layout engines have the capability to substitute other fonts if the main font doesn't have a glyph for the current character. This is probably what you're seeing.
2. It's exactly the same text in both fonts; the only issue is that not all fonts may have glyphs for all characters, so they will be unable to display the text properly.
3. You need to use an Input Method Editor in order to enter non-Roman text with a Roman keyboard; see your OS documentation for details.

Comment: @Ignacio: regarding answer to 1, if glyphs are missing, then would layout engine search for missing glyph in all installed fonts and use the first one found? What would be the logic? How could I know the exact font used, if it is replaced by engine?

Comment: Depends on the engine. Under GNOME you can use Character Map to determine what fontconfig has decided to use. Dunno about Uniscribe (Windows) or Core Text (OS X) though.

Comment: @Ignacio: PLease see my edit3 above. I think my question should be more clear now.

Comment: My answer remains. If you have fonts that don't follow the Unicode codepoints then there's nothing that can be done about it.

Comment: @Ignacio: Could you please tell me the steps for 'Character Map to determine what fontconfig has decided to use' in Ubuntu?

Comment: Pick the font you want to use as a base from the pulldown, then right-click-hold over the character. The name of the font used will be in the bottom of the small window that pops up.